# How do you handle image control in WPF windows application

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, windows

I have a vb.net 2010 application that includes a picturebox which is under the control of a camera dll. The dll loads an camera preview into the picturebox. Below is the code for preview the camera in vb.net windows application.

```
camera_object = New ISH10_U3
Res = camera_object.CameraInit(TS_CMOS10MP_RESOLUTION.CMOS10MP_3664_2740, 
PictureBox1.Handle, Me.Handle, 1)
If Res = TS_CMOS10MP_STATUS.STATUS_OK Then
    Res = camera_object.CameraPlay()
Else
    MsgBox("CAMERA NOT CONNECTED")
End If
```

I want to preview the camera in WPF windows Application. In WPF I'm using an Image control to preview the camera.

```
Res = camera_object.CameraInit(TS_CMOS10MP_RESOLUTION.CMOS10MP_3664_2740, 
      PictureBox1.Handle, Me.Handle, 1)
```

The above camera_object.CameraInit(), function I want to send the picture box name and form name. But, **PictureBox1.Handle** and **Me.handle** are not available in WPF windows applications. Any suggestion will be a great for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, WPF doesn't have handles. There are Interop classes for entire windows but not single controls (simply put WinForms = GDI, WPF = DirectX). You could try putting your existing code into a WindowsFormsHost but maybe there is an updated version of the dll you are using.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer does i want to update the code in DLL or there is any conversion avaliable for handles in wpf

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, my previous comment answered exactly that. WPF doesn't have handles.